# Partial Derivatives and the Cauchy-Riemann equation

Tags: calculus

> Show that if $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations and 
>   if $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, then

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}= \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}$

> and

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}= -\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}$

> now the Cauchy-Riemann equations are:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$

> proceeding

$u=u(x,y)$ , $v=v(x,y)$
  $u=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, $v=v(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$

> by the Chain Rule

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial u}{\partial\ x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial\ r}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial u}{\partial\ x}\cos(\theta)+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\sin(\theta)$

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}= \frac{\partial v}{\partial\ x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}$

$=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(-r\sin\theta)+ \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(r\cos\theta)$

$\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}= -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(\sin\theta)+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(\cos\theta)$

> and now repeat for

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = -\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}$

> But where to from here?

Comment: Hint : use the Cauchy Riemann equations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You derived the relation $$\frac{du}{dr} = \frac{du}{dx}\cos(\theta) + \frac{du}{dy}\sin(\theta).$$ Making use of the Cauchy Riemann equations we can rewrite this as $$\frac{du}{dr} = \frac{dv}{dy}\cos(\theta) - \frac{dv}{dx}\sin(\theta).$$ Using the above and also your derived relation for $dv/d\theta$ we get that $$\frac{dv}{d\theta} = -\frac{dv}{dx}r\sin(\theta) + \frac{dv}{dy}r\cos(\theta) = r\left(\frac{dv}{dy}\cos(\theta) - \frac{dv}{dx}\sin(\theta)\right) = r\frac{du}{dr}.$$ The other relation is derived similarly.